# How find the poles/residues of $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x^2 \, dx}{1 + x^4}$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I'm trying to find the poles/residues of this integral:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x^2 \, dx}{1 + x^4}$$

I've been given this attempt for a solution, but I don't really understand the procedure for how the poles are found.

**EDIT:**

From the solution on the bottom of this post:

Specifically I don't see how: 
$ \frac{p(z)}{q'(z)} = \frac{z^2}{4z^3} = \frac{1}{4z} .$

becomes this:

$ \frac{p(z)}{q'(z)} = - \frac{z^3}{4} $

What exactly is happening here?

**END EDIT**

As I understand it there should be $2$ poles, each of order $1$.

> [image: solution to the problem]

Comment: To find the poles you need to find the roots of $x^4 +1 = 0$ i.e. you need to compute the fourth roots of $-1$.

Comment: Your user name reminded me of this old [song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oW7C5Zd5pEc&t=13). :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

- Fist find the roots of $z^4 = -1$.
- Choose a path containg $2$ of those roots. Say a semi-circunference of radius $R > 1$.
- Use the following Theorem:

> If $p$ and $q$ are functions, analytic at $z_0$, with $p(z_0) \neq 0$ and $q(z_0) = 0$ and $q'(z_0) \neq 0$ then $z_0$ is a simple pole of $p(z)/q(z)$ and $$\mathrm{Res}_{z=z_0} \frac{p(z)}{q(z)}= \frac{p(z_0)}{q'(z_0)}$$

what are $p$ and $q$?

Comment: Adding to bullet #2, there is a lemma that states that if $f=Q(z)/P(z)$ is a quotient of two polynomials s.t. $degree Q \ge 2+degree P$, then $lim_{\rho \rightarrow \infty} \int_{C^+_\rho} f(z)\ dz = 0$. Meaning, you can take your closing contour to be a semi-circle in the upper half plane in this circumstance.

Comment: Ah... I meant if $f=P(z)/Q(z)$. Sorry.

Comment: $p(z) = x^2$.
$q(z) = 1 + x^4$. 
so  $q'(z) = 4x^3$

Comment: Thanks!
But IMO $ \frac{p(z)}{q'(z)} = \frac{z^2}{4z^3} = \frac{1}{4z} $  and not :  $\frac{p(z)}{q'(z)} = - \frac{z^3}{4}$ as the solution claims.
What am I missing?

Comment: First, it's not $z$ and rather $z_k$ with $k = 0, 1$. Now multiply your fraction by $\frac{z^4_k}{z^4_k}$ and notice that $z^4_k = -1$.

Comment: hmm I don't think I understand, cause by multiplying with the fraction you mention the output will still be unchanged, since: $ \frac{1}{z^4_k}  \frac{z^4_k}{z^4_k} = \frac{1}{z^4_k} $
If I insert numerical values for one of the poles into the expression $\frac{1}{4z_k}$ I get: 
$\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{2^3} (1+i)} $ (from where the square root comes from $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2*2}$)which I don't see how reduces to $- \frac{z^3_k}{4}$

Comment: Pay attention, you're multiplying $\frac{1}{4 z_k}$ by $\frac{z^4_k}{z^4_k}$. I'll let you figure this out now, it's important you try.

Comment: Thank you, If I multiplied by $ \frac{z_k}{z_k} $ instead I got
 $\frac{z^2_k}{z^3_k}  \frac{z^1_k}{z^1_k} = \frac{z^3_k}{-1} $ which is the desired result since it can be verified that $z^4_k = -1$

Comment: That's it! You got it! I'm glad I could help.